# How can I access an element of an associative Array in handlebars with dynamic id?

Tags: arrays, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am currently trying to access an associative array inside of an emberjs handlebars file. Accessing through hardcoded values is no problem, but I want to get the element based on a dynamic "index".

The code I have so far is

```
{{#each this.model.ambient as |sound|}}
  <Ambientsound @buttonActive={{soundPlayers.[Bells]}} @sound={{sound}} @updateFunction={{action "updateSound"}}/>
{{/each}}
```

and the relevant section of the controller is:

```
soundPlayers: {"Bells":100,"Fireplace":30}
```

The code I have above works perfectly fine, but now I am trying to access the soundPlayers.[...] based on the value of sound.id, like so:

```
{{#each this.model.ambient as |sound|}}
  <Ambientsound @buttonActive={{soundPlayers.[sound.id]}} @sound={{sound}} @updateFunction={{action "updateSound"}}/>
{{/each}}
```

The Value in sound.id is passed as a string and there's nothing I can do about that.

How can I cast sound.id into something that allows me to access the array, or phrase the handlebars query in a way so I can get the result from the array? I could also consider reshaping the array I have in my controller. Anything that helps is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should do `{{soundPlayers.Bells}}`.
Next you can use the `get` helper:

```
  <Ambientsound @buttonActive={{get soundPlayers sound.id}} @sound={{sound}} @updateFunction={{action "updateSound"}}/>
```

Comment: Hey Lux thanks for the respond. Unfortunately that didn't help. Using `@buttonActive={{soundPlayers.[Bells]}}` without the `get` works perfectly fine. Using the `get` only returns null.

The problematic part is getting the sound.id into the soundPlayers[sound.id]. Any ideas on how I could do that?

Comment: Sorry was a copy paste error. Now the answer should be correct

Comment: Oh wow thanks so much! Didn't realize this was even an option! Thank you so much! It works now. :)